# 12 Characters Including leading and following zeros

Tags: excel

I am finding this difficult to explain, but ultimately I am wanting a cells value to be 12 characters long including +/- a decimal point and following zeroes.

```
Examples are
1200 would become +1200.000000
-20 would become -20.00000000
99999999 would become +99999999.00
```

I have tried `FIXED`, `LENGTH`, and formatting rules with no joy. The formatting rules only changed what the number displayed as, not what the value of the cell was.

Can someone help me with this? Is it possible to do it only with formulae and no scripting?

Comment: This may be in the wrong place, but it is where I was brought search 'Excel stackexchange'. If it is wrong could it be moved please.

Comment: Do you want the cell to still be a numeric type after all this? Could it be text instead?

Comment: I think it would be best as text, but it isn't a priority.

Comment: What about values with decimals?

Comment: You mean for example if the number is 22.6? It would become +22.60000000 OR +000000022.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User the formula

```
=LEFT(TEXT(A1,"+0.000000000;-0.000000000"),12)
```

where A1 contains your number. This will be a text cell type but will format the cell exactly how you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the numbers we are using will break the formula as you mentioned. we need it to support from the lowest possible number with 12 characters, to the highest with 12 characters. I will add this to my question so clarify.

Comment: How would I incorporate MOD in to this formula?

Comment: Fixed now I understand the question more. The MOD is not relevant.

Comment: I appreciate your time. I'll give it a try shortly.

Comment: I still don't get how this works according to the OP's format as this adds some 0's at the start and some at the end which is not what the OP showed

Comment: @chancea It didn't: let's publish jointly. I've amended. It will *always* display at least two characters on the left of the decimal, which I *think* is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Bathsheba I see now that you updated, that is probably is a better format overall, i.e. `+0.###` compared to `+.###`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole formula, if a little long:

```
=MID(MID(TEXT(A1,"+"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)&";-"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)),1,1)&MID(TEXT(A1,"+"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)&";-"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)),SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND({".",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},TEXT(A1,"+"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)&";-"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)))),FIND({".",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},TEXT(A1,"+"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)&";-"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)))),1),LEN(TEXT(A1,"+"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)&";-"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)))-SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND({".",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},TEXT(A1,"+"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)&";-"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)))),FIND({".",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},TEXT(A1,"+"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)&";-"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)))),1)),1,12)
```

Here is a screen shot to show the formatted results:

[image]

Explanation:

1. We need to wrap the cell in:

   ```
   =TEXT(A1,"+"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12)&";-"&REPT("0",12)&"."&REPT("0",12))
   ```

   Which gets us the +/- sign and up to 12 0's on the front of the number and up to 12 0's on the end of the number. This is to accommodate for whole numbers up to 12 characters long and up to pure decimal numbers with all numbers past the decimal point.
2. Now we just need to get rid of the excess 0's; to do that we need to find the first occurrence of a `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9 or "."` we can achieve this with this:

   ```
   =SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND({".",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},D1)),FIND({".",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},D1)),1)
   ```

   (where D1 is the text from step 1)
3. Now we can use `MID` to eliminate the beginning excess and trailing 0's that we don't want like so:

   ```
   =MID(MID(D1,1,1)&MID(D1,E1,LEN(D1)-E1),1,12)
   ```

   (where D1 again is from step 1 and E1 is from step 2)

Combining all these yields the long formula, and the first formula I showed, but the output is correct.

Comment: I haven't tested your answer because I already found a solution, but if it works it sure doesn't deserve a downvote. Perhaps someone thought it was too long?

Comment: @Terry What do you consider to be "lowest possible number with 12 characters"

Comment: It's a pity this is downvoted as i) it's correct, and ii) SO works better if different solution techniques are offered.

Comment: -99999999999 would be the lowest number.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks for the edit, (it is hard to look at things from another's point of view sometimes) after looking at it now I can see how I kind of set myself up for what I got with how I stated it originally.  Live and learn